# Testing a non angular website using Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am trying to test my website which is a non angular website through Protractor. My code is:

```
describe("Supplier Portal: Login ", function () {
    //ui.setSmallScreenSize();
    // ui.testLogger(100);
    it("test", co.wrap(function* () {
         browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

        yield browser.driver.get("https://cit.supplier.ext.here.com/");
        yield element(by.xpath("//*[@id=\"rnav\"]/li[2]/a")).click();

       var elmOK = element(by.xpath( "//*[@id=\"sign-in-email\"]"));
       browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(elmOK.getWebElement()))

    }));
});
```

But when I try to execute the code I got the following error:

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //*[@id="sign-in-email"])
```

But the element is there on the website.

Please advice what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on a non-angular site and using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`, Protractor will not wait for the `angular` variable to become available, so it starts firing tests off because it thinks the app is ready, more info [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md).

You need to manipulate the [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) by using [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) so Protractor knows that it is waiting for something.  This will make your tests more consistent and reliable.

A few examples to guide you:

Wait for an element to be loaded/present in the DOM:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var ele = element(by.css('div.class'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele), 5000);
```

The 5000 parameter value I passed in says wait a *maximum* of 5 seconds, if not present in 5 seconds then fail.

Wait for an element visible:

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele), 5000);
```

Wait for an element to be clickable:

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(ele), 5000);
```

Again, it's important to note that these are implicit waits and they will wait a *maximum* of the time parameter provided.  It is not a guaranteed amount of time to wait, they fire off ASAP when they find the element you told it to wait for.